# I want to download a whole github repo and overwrite the local file with the new download

Tags: python, github

I want to download a whole github repo and overwrite the local file with the new download. Any idea on how to do this with python.

```
import requests
import json

def lookForUpdates():
        git_api_request = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo")
        git_api = json.loads(git_api_request.content)
        updatedString = git_api["updated_at"]
        if(updatedString == "2021-11-30T08:33:16Z"):  
                smUpdate = requests.get('https://github.com/user/repository/tree/master/')
lookForUpdates()
```

Basically, I am checking to see if there was an update to the repository, if there is I want to redownload the whole thing and overwrite the current directory.

Comment: Any reason to not just use `git pull` with appropriate config to always force an overwrite from the server?

Comment: Because I will be putting this on a raspberry pi in an inclosed environment. I guess I could use git pull. But I really do not want to download git on every machine. @match